# How to load nib in a ViewController on a placeholderView

Tags: swift, subview, nib

I have a view controller that has a `placeholder` view, i also have a custom `nib` that i want to add to that placeHolderView. I am struggling to figure out how i go about registering the nib in the viewController so that when i push to this view controller the placeholder view is replaced with my nib.

This is what i have attempted:

**CountryViewController**

```
import UIKit

class CountryViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var flagImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var countryInfoViewPlaceHolder: UIView!

    private let countryDetails: CountryData

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpNavBar(countryName: countryDetails.name)
        addSubView()
    }

    init(countryDetails: CountryData) {
        self.countryDetails = countryDetails
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        return nil
    }


    func setUpNavBar(countryName: String) {
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        self.title = countryName
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.countryThemeGrey()
    }

    func addSubView() {
        guard let nibView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CountryDetailsView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? CountryDetailsView else {
            return
        }
        countryInfoViewPlaceHolder.addSubview(nibView)
    }
}
```

**CountryDetailsView**

```
class CountryDetailsView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var capitalLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var regionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var subRegionLabel: UILabel!

    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: .zero)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        return nil
    }

    private func commonInit() {
//        let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: type(of: self)), bundle: nil)
//        contentView = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
//        addSubviewPinnedToEdges(contentView)
        Bundle(for: CountryDetailsView.self).loadNibNamed("CountryDetailsView", owner: self, options: nil)
    }

    func setViewWithData(country: CountryData) {
        capitalLabel.text = country.capital
        regionLabel.text = country.region
        subRegionLabel.text = country.subRegion
    }

}
```

Comment: problem is here -> `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        return nil
    }`

Comment: what should i return

Comment: Alright i figured it i added : super.init(coder: aDecoder) and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add static method. Like below

```
class CountryDetailsView: UIView {

@IBOutlet weak var capitalLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var regionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var subRegionLabel: UILabel!

static func initView() -> CountryDetailsView {
    return Bundle(for: CountryDetailsView.self).loadNibNamed(String(describing: CountryDetailsView.self), owner: self, options: nil)!.first as! CountryDetailsView
}

func setViewWithData(country: CountryData) {
    capitalLabel.text = country.capital
    regionLabel.text = country.region
    subRegionLabel.text = country.subRegion
}
}
```

Use:

```
func addSubView() {
    let nibView = CountryDetailsView.initView()
    countryInfoViewPlaceHolder.addSubview(nibView)
}
```